# EMF EObject with last modified time-stamp

Tags: eclipse-emf

How can I declare a time-stamp-like property for an EObject that's assigned every time a setter changes the value of any (EMF-modelled) property of the object.

```
public interface ReviewObject extends EObject {
    /**
     * @generated
     */
    void setLastModified(Date value); // This should be invoked each time a child class's
                                      // setter changes any property
}
```

I'd prefer to handle it within a method of the 'ReviewObject'-s implementors and not to write a serialization- or transaction based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.Adapter` (see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEMFNotification/article.html for more information) and add your Adapter to all the relevant ReviewObjects. Upon notification, analyze whether it is a model change and call your `setLastModified` method. Note that you must make sure your adapter is placed anytime your model is loaded so you may need to find a way to instantiate it "automagically".

There may be another solution by making your generated model code inherit some ReviewObject which customizes method `eSet(...)` such that `setLastModified` is called. You will have to ensure this `eSet` method is called by every setter (I am not sure it is the case by default). You may have to tickle with the dynamic/reflective method invocation setting for that.

Comment: I was eyeing the eSet() method but ReviewObjectImpl is also a generated class and I don't think I should modify it's content. The Adapter approach works perfectly, thank you!